# Google chrome.storage.sync: if multiple Google accounts log in and out of the same computer does their data get shared?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the [`chrome.storage.sync` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) as part of a Google Chrome extension that I'm building.

I sometimes need to get all the synced data and I do that by using:

`chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) { //do stuff with the results } );`

I've just been testing this out by logging into Gmail with different accounts and it appears that the data is shared between them (I was online the whole time). **What's going on? I thought that using `chrome.storage.sync` would sync data to each user's Google account?**

In the API it says:

> When using storage.sync, the stored data will automatically be synced
>   to any Chrome browser that the user is logged into, provided the user
>   has sync enabled.

What exactly does 'logged into' mean in this context? Does it mean signed into (via a Google account) or just opened?

Comment: Logged into the browser means signed into it, of course. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: @wOxxOm I wanted to confirm because it appears that the data is syncing to all the Google accounts that I'm logging into on my computer.

Comment: Logging into a computer, browser, gmail. Those are three different things. Only on ChromeOS the first two may be the same, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to chrome://settings you will see a Sign in section (probably at the very top). This is the account that will be used for chrome app synchronization.

Answer (score -1):

Google chrome just will save the data in the user that you are using in that moment even if you have more users logged.